# How to reference the users current textbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access, null, textbox, focus

In access I am trying to not let the user exit a textbox unless they have filled it out (i.e. not left it null). This is to be done in a function in order to cut down on code. In VBA is there some way to stop the user from exiting the function? (I know about setting the focus but I need the code to work from a multitude of different textboxes)

For reference my current code is as follows;

```
Function Reload()

 If IsNull(EmployeeID.Value) Or IsNull([First Name].Value) Or IsNull([Surname].Value) Or IsNull(DOB.Value) Or IsNull(Position.Value) Or IsNull(Position.Value) Or IsNull(Mobile.Value) Or IsNull(Email.Value) Or IsNull(Address.Value) Or IsNull(Suburb.Value) Or IsNull(Postcode.Value) Or IsNull([Start Date].Value) Or IsNull(UserLogin.Value) Or IsNull(UserPassword.Value) Then
   MsgBox "Please fill out all fields"
 Else
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
   Form.Refresh
 End If

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Let Reload take a parameter of the text box object, then just reference the parameter name in the null check?

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't really help us determine what's not working. Can you be more specific?

Comment: sorry. I am using Me.Self.SetFocus with self being the textbox object. It gives me a compile error

Answer (score 0):

The best technique I know is to use the `BeforeUpdate` event to run data validation. Using your if statements if the data is not valid then set

```
Cancel = True
```

and the data will not write. You would probably prefer to disable the default record navigation and form close buttons and use custom buttons so that you can trap the invalid data error and prevent moving to a new record or closing the form. But even if you allow the user to use the built in navigation buttons or close button Access will throw up error messages about being unable to save the current record and prompt the user if he wants to proceed.

You can also go a step further and captue which fields are invalid and present a message box.

```
Msgbox ("The following fields were left blank and must be entered to save this record:" & vbCrLf & "Field 1" & vbCrLf & "Field 2")
```

Comment: Sergey, I'd like to know how you made the edits so the code appeared how it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification of the text input limiter i use in our chat room should help. New function I have called it MustINPUT and call it on the LostFocus of the text boxes that you don't want to move from with out input.

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_LostFocus()
    Call MustINPUT (Me.MyTextBox, 0)
End Sub
```

Just change the message for your users.

```
Sub MustINPUT(ctl As Control, iMaxLen As Integer)

'Call MustINPUT(Me.txtSayThis, 0)

    If Len(ctl.Text) = iMaxLen Then
        MsgBox "Please Type something", vbExclamation, "Input Needed"
        ctl.Text = Left(ctl.Text, iMaxLen)
        ctl.SelStart = iMaxLen
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this help. DR ,